# How do I increase the output width of JupyterLab in my browser?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In the original Jupyter notebooks, it was possible to increase cell output width with the following command:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

In JupyterLab, the above command has no effect, but I would still like to expand my cell output width.

Thanks!

*Re-tested on 9/29/18, this feature appears to be working now.